# How do I traverse nested arrays/objects in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, trello

I'm trying to display multiple checklists from individual cards in Trello. I can get access to the checklist as multiple, nested objects but I don't know how to traverse deeper to pull out the actual text and make it list items.

```
 Trello.get("cards/" + cardID + "/checklists", function(checklists) {
   console.log(checklists);
 });
```

[the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY3m1.png)

data: http://jsbin.com/OzEdUkU/2/edit

How do I traverse all the way down to the name of the checkItem array objects?

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, could you include a sample response as a javascript object instead of just the log output?

Comment: How do I include a sample response as a javascript object? I'm new to this. I get this error when I try your answer: [Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.length')
 each (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2)
 (anonymous function) (trello.js, line 44)
 n (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 2)
 w (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 4)
 d (jquery-1.7.1.min.js, line 4)

Comment: write it out: http://jsbin.com/OzEdUkU/1/edit

Comment: Actually, try this. `console.log(JSON.stringify(checklists))` I need the string that it prints in the console log...put it in that jsbin, click share, save changes, and comment the link for me.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/OzEdUkU/2/edit?html,js,output thank you

Comment: I updated my answer with details and a demo showing that it now works. Also note the process that we got your log content into a javascript variable in my demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes care of everything in your data set. [**Live demo here (click).**](http://jsbin.com/OzEdUkU/3/edit)

```
$.each(checkList, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  $.each(obj.checkItems, function(j, checkItem) {
    console.log(checkItem);
  });
});
```

`checkList` is an array (set) of objects. In your sample data, there are two objects nested in `checkList`, so the first `$.each` is for each object.

Each object has some properties with string values and the property `checkList` itself is an array, so the second `$.each` is looping through that object's `checkItems` array. `checkItems` only contains properties with string values, so there is no additional nesting.

Also note that `$.each` is just a jQuery shorthand function for traditional for loops and could be replaced with a normal for loop or the newer built-in js function `forEach`.